# HDMI works only in Wayland

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, kde, hdmi

I just installed my old video-card in computer to use it's HDMI-port (as my motherboard port seems to be broken). So, I connected hdmi-cable to video-card port.

Now I have the following situation -- Wayland works just fine with HDMI, but X11 session only shows black screen when switching to HDMI.

Comment: If you swap your videocard to a different brand, you probably also need to ensure that the correct video driver is being used.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I didn't have any videocard previously. I'm using AMD APU with integrated videochip, and now I additionally added my old AMD Radeon HD videocard just for HDMI, and the mentioned problem occured

Comment: You probably still need to have the Radeon driver installed.   Easiest might be to install the proprietary driver - https://itsfoss.com/install-additional-drivers-ubuntu/

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I tried to install AMD Catalyst, which is the proprietary driver for my card -- it didn't worked out, since it is outdated, and simply doesn't install on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Anyway, I don't thing it's the issue since everything works just fine in Wayland session (except Wayland's own bugs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found what was the issue. I just needed to press Meta+P and choose another display.